# maven cxf-codegen-plugin för wsdl2java, how to handle nested xsd:import

Tags: maven-plugin, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I have an main wsdl file that xsd:import a lot of xdd from online, for example

```
<xsd:import schemalocation="https://file/file1.xsd" namespace="file1">
<xsd:import schemalocation="https://file/file1.xsd" namespace="file2">
<xsd:import schemalocation="https://file/file1.xsd" namespace="file3">
```

but in xsd file also import xsd such as in file1.xsd, it may import file2

```
<xsd:import schemalocation="https://file/file1.xsd" namespace="file2">
```

this leads to 'Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class', Those xdd are filethat contains a lot of declarations, how should I generate code from them?

using bindingFiles? how to create binding files that tell plugin to ignore duplicated import?